# How Do You Turn Off Music With The playsound Module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-playsound

In my game, I'm using the Playsound Python module in Python version 2.7. I can get a sound to play using the commands shown in the documentation. But I can't find how to turn the sound off.

```
from playsound import playsound # Imports Library To Play Sound

def playy():
    playsound('music.mp3')

T = Thread(target=playy)
T.start()
```

The `T` is part of multithreading so the program plays music while the game runs. The `playsound` function above plays the sound I want but it won't turn off. I've tried many things like `playsound = False`. But I can't seem to turn it off.

Comment: Where is `playsound` coming from?  There's nothing by that name in `pysound`.

Comment: its an import from a library.

Comment: Yes but which one?  Add the `import` statement to your question so there's no ambiguity.

Comment: ok, just did. ty

Comment: From the source for the [`playsound`](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) module, it doesn't look like it supports turning off the sound. Since it's Pure Python, you could theoretically modify it and add that capability. It plays the actually sounds differently on various platforms, providing support for all of them might be a quite a bit of work…

Comment: The problem you are having is strongly attributed to multithreading. In python you cant kill a thread easily. Research on how to kill a thread.